# Pandas - iterate over dataframe rows and update df (one line of code)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

having the following code below.
Scenario description:

Iterate over the dataframe having the list of URLs Send GET request. Create initially 3 new columns and update them based on the results from the previous get request.

Question:
Is there any option how to do write the 3 "df.set_value" in one line of code??

Many thanks in advance

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

d = {'ListOfURLs': ['URL1', 'URL2', 'URL3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

#print(df)
s = requests.session()
s.post(login_url, login_data)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    r = s.get(row['ListOfURLs'])
    r.status_code
    if r.status_code == 200:
        # Update Dataframe , create initially 3 new columns and update them based on the results from the previous get request
        df.set_value(index, 'Status Code', r.status_code)
        df.set_value(index, 'Result', '[OK]')
        df.set_value(index, 'Error', np.nan)
```

Comment: Why don't extract the data first and then build the DataFrame?

Comment: Data would be extracted from cvs file, the main goal is to update the df based on the results coming from the GET requests. I’m trying to figure out how to update the df ideally with one line of code.

Comment: And what would be the value for status_code != 200?

Comment: You can omit this part, actually.. I’m interested the most how to write the last 3 lines into 1 line.

Comment: Possibly a question for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchage.com)?

Comment: @hd1 This is not a request for review, but a request for specific rewrite. Wouldn't do well there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import numpy as np

d = {'ListOfURLs': ['https://stackoverflow.com/q/65060875/4001592',
                    'https://stackoverflow.com/q/65060875/4001592',
                    'https://stackoverflow.com/q/65060875/4001592']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    r = requests.get(row['ListOfURLs'])
    if r.status_code == 200:
        df.at[index, ['Status Code', 'Result', 'Error']] = (r.status_code, '[OK]', np.nan)

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
                                     ListOfURLs  Status Code Result  Error
0  https://stackoverflow.com/q/65060875/4001592        200.0   [OK]    NaN
1  https://stackoverflow.com/q/65060875/4001592        200.0   [OK]    NaN
2  https://stackoverflow.com/q/65060875/4001592        200.0   [OK]    NaN
```

Don't use [set_value](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html):

> Deprecated since version 0.21.0: Use .at[] or .iat[] accessors
> instead.

Notice that some details from your original question were omitted to produce an actual output.